# Where is the team menu in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: azure-devops, devops, visual-studio-2022

There is no `Team` menu in Visual Studio 2022 and instead of it, there is a `Git` menu, but in this new `Git` menu it is not possible to connect to the Asure DevOps server. What replaces the team menu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect Visual Studio 2022 to Azure DevOps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70274860/how-to-connect-visual-studio-2022-to-azure-devops)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2022, the `Git` menu is displayed by default instead of the `Team` menu. To show the `Team` menu, just go to the `View` menu and open `Team Explorer`. When you connect to the Devops server, the `Team` menu will show and the `Git` will hide.

Default of visual studio 2022:

[image: Default of visual studio 2022]

After connect to Devops server:

[image: After connect to Devops server]